# Google IP sends a TCP (ACK, PSH) to my router. Known why?

Tags: networking, firewall, routing

I am monitoring my traffic and noticed several **TCP (ACK, PSH)**  connection attempts on my router's input chain, which gets dropped by my firewall.

The log looks like that:

```
Dropping input: src-mac 9c:80:df:a0:8a:dd, proto TCP (ACK,PSH), 172.217.16.78:443 (google ip) ->192.168.1.2:40382 (my router IP), len 115
```

Obviously this is dropped because my last rule on my input chain is to drop packets.

I do not understand the TCP protocol well enough, so sorry if this is a bit naive, but why is the request directed to my router?

I have various devices that uses google services and probably third party software as well, but it is very confusing to me, why the packet is actually sent *to* the router and not *nat'ed* to a device in my network (which would be the forward chain, right?).

I have not yet noticed a degraded experience with my devices regarding google products. Software updates, push notifications etc all seem to work correctly.

Comment: It's probably the last ACK of a closed connection.

Comment: You could try increasing various netfilter tcp parameters ( `/proc/sys/net/netfilter/nf_conntrack_tcp_timeout_*` ) and see if those spurious logs disappear (at the cost of possible extra memory usage)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The phenomenon is somewhat more complex. I did some research in the according logs and want to share my guess here for all whom wondering too.

The related log entries showing drops in the input chain with TCP flags `ACK` and `PSH` (push). This indicates that some service in the network is awaiting messages from the google servers (via. push). But wait - why the package is logged in the input chain? Thats rather easy to explain - if the router  (or as @chexum already mentioned - the conntrack) has no connection information about `NAT`ed/`PAT`ed traffic the package looks like traffic for the router and not for any devices behind it. So that explains why "google is sending traffic to the router".

But the question is why the router has no connection information for these packages. 
And here i can only speculate for now: The drops are observed in times where most users are at the internet. My guess is that googles replies took to long (mybe because it prior push traffic lower than other) so that the connection times out. The timeouts on this particular router are about 10s for TCP packages and 5s for `SYN`. After some more time the conntrack will remove his memory about old "invalid" traffic and from that time on every traffic from this connection looks like input traffic.
Thats also one possible explanation why the invalid rules are not triggered.

I think @samuel should observe it a little more and see if any pattern is recognizable. But generally i sare @chexum oppinion that these drops are ignorable.

Answer (score 3):

It's clearly showing a packet received from a Google IP, with a source port of 443.

There is of course the possibility that someone does a man-in-the-middle attack with Google IP address, or even that someone from (or broken into) Google is sending you packets, yes, but this is very, **very** unlikely.

What's more likely is that your packet filter, and/or the conntrack subsystem (or a similar functionality on your router and/or on your ISP) already has seen packets from the packet flow between google:443 and yourip:40382 showing the connection to be closed already.

Typically connections initiated by you are not logged by the packet filters, but that's only true for established connections.

When the connections are closed down with a `FIN` from both sides or `RST` from either side, the connection is no longer considered `ESTABLISHED`.  Any packets delayed or resent by either side will then be considered new, and log-worthy by your packet filter, especially if the removed conntrack entry prevents de-nating the packet to its proper destination.

This is very common, there is probably no reason to worry at all, you can usually safely ignore those logged packets.

If you see any pattern, and want to investigate, you can keep a `tcpdump` running on your system logging all packets from similar IP addresses, then when you see one more similar log, you can stop the tcpdump, and filter for the local port to see if you indeed had a connection open just a few seconds before the event.

A sample tcpdump for the above would be something like:

```
tcpdump -ieth0 -s0 -w /var/tmp/allssl.cap port 443
```

Comment: I indeed have an accept rule for established and related packets on the input chain. However I also have a drop rule for invalid packets (out of order etc), which does not log anything. That's why I am confused why those packets pass through the firewall to the very last drop (which does also the logging). I might need to tcpdump indeed some traffic to dig into that. Thanks